# How to make CSS suggestions to appear in JetBrains IDE (e.g. PyCharm) for Nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, pycharm, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, jetbrains-ide

Can somebody please tell me how to make CSS suggestions to appear in JetBrains IDE (e.g. PyCharm)?
I have them working on regular Vue projects with Vuetify, but in the Nuxt project, they don't appear.

This is what I have in Vue project and want the same in Nuxt, kindly see below:

[image: Vue project]

Comment: it should work in Nuxt just in the same way as in Vue.js apps. Where do you have your CSS selectors defined? Are the corresponding `.css` files included in project?

Comment: @lena `.css` files are included in `node_modules`. I created another fresh project using `create-app` (nuxt's standard CLI tool, which I believe should have the most correct settings) with Vuetify and it also doesn't do suggestions. The thing I ended up with is adding the vuetify.css into `/assets/` folder and adding it to `.gitignore`. But I think someone should know what's exactly wrong with it. So that's why I keep this question up.

Comment: so it's all about classes in `node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.css`?

Comment: @lena Yes, thanks for the help. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetbrains IDEs, `node_modules` folders are excluded from project for better performance, only direct dependencies listed in `package.json` are indexed.

in Nuxt applications created with `create-app`, `vuetify` is not a direct dependency, so it's excluded from indexing, and no completion is available. Adding `"vuetify": "*"` to your project `package.json` and re-opening the project should help